# Call generics with base class gives cannot convert from base class to T

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following setup and it seems that my object cannot be converted to the generic type. While it is actually the base class. Why doesn't this work? It seems so logical to me.

```
public class AList<T> where T : A
{
    void DoStuff(T foo)
    {
    }

    void CallDoStuff()
    {
        DoStuff(new A()); // ERROR: Cannot convert A to T
    }
}

public class A
{
}
```

Comment: My +1 because sometimes, there is some errors that open our eyes for even new (and further) dimensions in our lovely C# language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the constraint says that `T` must be `A` *or a class derived from `A`*.
Now, when you instantiate `AList` with a concrete type, `T` is a very specific class. And if you didn't instantiate `AList` with `A` itself but with a subclass of it, `T` is a subclass of `A`.

You can't convert an instance with a runtime type of the base class to one of its subclasses, as it misses all the information that is being added by the subclass.

Example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

Derived d = new Base();
```

Would you expect that code to work? Surely not, because a `Cat` is also a `Animal` but a `Animal` is not a `Cat`.
If you would expect the above code to actually work, ask yourself what is supposed to happen when the following code is executed: `d.Bar = 42;`
`Animal` doesn't contain a definition for `Bar`.

The same is happening in your code - it's just a little bit more obscured with the generics in the game.

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense. I just forgot that this explicit typing obliges me to make sure that all objects here could be of <B>, instead of <A>. So maybe I shouldn't use generics in the first place if I want to do this.

Comment: @Marnix: Correct. If you don't want to enforce a certain subclass of `A` but want to allow all subclasses and `A` itself at the same time: Don't use generics.

Answer (score 2):

`T` could be also a class that derives from `A` so you can't put instance of `A` as a parameter of type `T`. Something like invoking method, that takes `int` with and argument that is of type `object`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same reason that is an `object` can not be converted to `int` implicitly.

The method expects a child class and you are passing the parent, so you need an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking T to extend A. So you can replace T with A but not A with T.

if Cat : Animal it doesn't mean you can always convert an Animal to a Cat.

Comment: Good logic, I would put is this way "if Cat : Animal, it does not means that ANY Animal is a Cat".

Answer (score 0):

Try and use `Activator` to give you an instance of `A` from `T` because you know that `T` has to be `A` due to your constraint, so there isn't a need to use `new A()` anywhere as you have `T`, so you can just create an instance of `T`.

```
T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
DoStuff(obj);
```

Or do a cast of your `object` as other answers have mentioned, however this will not work in all cases.

```
T obj = (T)new A();
DoStuff(obj);
```